# How do you change the timezone in PHP for an existing timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, timezone

The code for the date and time function:

```
function date_and_time($format,$timestamp) {

$date_and_time = date($format,$timestamp);
return $date_and_time;

}
```

And then the code to display it:

```
    <?php

        echo date_and_time("dS F Y", strtotime($profile[last_activity_date_and_time]));

    ?>
```

The value of $profile[last_activity_date_and_time] is 2010-01-18 14:34:04

When displayed it shows up as 18th January 2010 - 02:34pm

But, is there any way to change the timezone it is displayed in?

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if this what you're looking for, but try [DateTime](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($yourTimestamp);
echo $datetime->getTimezone()->getName();
echo $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM);

$la_time = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$datetime->setTimezone($la_time);
echo $datetime->getTimezone()->getName();
echo $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

Comment: Other answers address adjusting the Timezone for new dates, however yours is the only one that addresses adjusting the Timezone for an existing date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set default time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: Yeah but that only seems to work with new timestamps, not existing ones