# How do you handle timezone difference calculation in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm being told that this below method of calculating the user's local time is sometimes not working.  What's the best way to do this in PHP?  What do you do?

```
public function getTimeOffset ($time) {
    $this->_cacheTimeOffset();  
    if ($this->timeOffsetExecuted) {
        $d = date("O");
        $neg = 1;

        if (substr($d, 0, 1) == "-") {
            $neg = -1;
            $d = substr($d, 1);
        }

        $h = substr($d, 0, 2)*3600;
        $m = substr($d, 2)*60;

        return $time + ($neg * ($h + $m) * -1) + (($this->timeOffset + $this->getDstInUse()) * 3600);
    }
    return $time;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DateTime extension, such as [DateTime::getOffset](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getoffset.php),
or [DateTimeZone::getOffset](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php)

Some countries might have perform several timezone update,
this method [DateTimeZone::getTransitions](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) reveal the transition history

Comment: I'm currently allowing a user to specify their timezone in their profile.  Are you saying that I should just be able to pull it dynamically via PHP and don't have to ask them their timezone?

Comment: @Webnet - You still need to user to place their current timezone into their profile. Probably, you can provide a list of timezone, and let let user to choose. `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers` able to provide a full list of timezone supported, details - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

Just answered a very similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196849/basic-php-timezones-conversion/4199239#4199239). I recommend you check that one out; I explained the two preferred ways of doing timezone offset calculation (using simple math, and then the `datetimezone` and `datetime` classes) pretty thoroughly.

> The first way would be the easiest
>   (and most logical) way, and that is to
>   store their offset (if you already
>   have it, that is) and multiply that by
>   3600 (1 hour in seconds), and then add
>   *that* value to the current unix timestamp to get their final time of
>   running.
>
> Another way to do it is to use the
>   `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes.
>   How these two classes work, as shown
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196849/basic-php-timezones-conversion/4199239#4199239), is that you create two
>   `DateTimeZone` objects, one with your
>   timezone and one with theirs; create
>   two `DateTime` objects with the first
>   parameters being `"now"` and the
>   second being the reference to the
>   `DateTimeZone` objects above
>   (respectively); and then call the
>   `getOffset` method on *your* timezone
>   object passing *their* timezone object
>   as the first parameter, ultimately
>   getting you the offset in seconds that
>   can be added to the current unix
>   timestamp to get the time that *their*
>   job needs to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Z');
```

returns the UTC offset in seconds.

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution:

```
<?php echo date('g:i a', strtotime("now + 10 hours 30 minutes")); ?>
```

Comment: This is only putting time formatting and does not relate to time zones at all.