# Calculate time equivalent respective to a users time zone and a fixed time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Below is some text I am working on that tells users what time an online sale begins respective to their local time zone. The online sale always begins at 9am Pacific Time, *but not every day*.

> Our online sale begins at **9am PDT**. Your local time, based on your
>   time zone setting, is **September 11, 2012 - 12:02 am HST**, which is
>   UTC **-10** or **3** hours **behind PDT**. The sale will begin at
>   **XXam** on local time.

In the example above, the users time zone is Pacific/Honolulu and is stored in the db, and also set in a session called user_tz when they sign in.

I have most of the variables calculated. I'm stuck on this part (The sale will begin at **XXam** on local time.) ...which is how to determine the local time equivalent of 9am Pacific Time, and whether the local time equivalent will be the *same day* or the *next day* depending on how far ahead of Pacific Time they are. For example, Melbourne Australia, the sale would begin, the next day, September 12 at 2:00am since Melbourne is 17 hours ahead of Pacific Time.

"XX" should be 6:00 am in the example above.

PHP Version 5.3.14

```
<?php
// gets the users time zone offset in seconds from UTC
// shown above as -10
$user_tz_offset = getTimeZoneOffset($_SESSION['user_tz']);

// gets the dst code of the timezone ...example: pdt or pst
// shown above as HST
$dateTime = new DateTime(); 
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($_SESSION['user_tz'])); 
$user_tz_dst = $dateTime->format('T'); 

// gets the difference in hours from Pacific time to the users time zone
// shown above as 3
$hours_diff = abs(($user_tz_offset - TZ_OFFSET)/3600);

// gets the users local time
// shown above as September 11, 2012 - 12:02 am HST
$user_time_now = date("F j, Y \- g:i a", (time()+$user_tz_offset));

// add a plus sign to time zones that are not negative
if( !strstr( $user_tz_offset, "-" ))
{
    $add_plus_sign = '+';
}

// determine whether we should say "ahead of" or "behind" respective to Pacific time
// TZ_OFFSET is a constant defined in config
if( $user_tz_offset < TZ_OFFSET)
{
    $behind_or_ahead = 'behind';
}
else
{
    $behind_or_ahead = 'ahead of';

}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299183/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299183/how-do-you-handle-timezone-difference-calculation-in-php)

Comment: Why not just say "The sale begins in X hours time"? It'll be much less confusing to your users.